# check MySQL if row is not exist, then insert (Without unique key)

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-update, not-exists

We have 2 tables like these:

1: posts

```
ID    Title    Hits
1    Title 1    4
2    Title 2    7
3    Title 3    19
4    Title 4    8
```

2: hits

```
ID    PostID     IP
1       2     5.9.9.45
2       3     5.9.9.45
3       2     72.5.4.9
4       4     5.9.9.45
```

Now we need one query that check if a row with a specific PostID AND IP address is not exist in 'hits' table, insert a new row and increase posts.Hits one unit (It's a counter).

We tested this query:

```
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (value) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field=value
```

But as you see, IP and PostID can not be unique key. They can duplicate for different users.
Is there any way to insert and update in one query if there isn't PostID+IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have unique ip's per post you do like @gordon-linoff said:

```
create unique index unq_hits_postid_ip on hits(postid, ip);
```

Then you can use the following syntax to "ignore" the insert:

```
insert into hits (postid, ip) values (2,'5.9.9.45') on duplicate key update id=id;
```

You can then use a trigger to make sure the hits column is updated when ip is inserted:

```
DELIMITER /

CREATE TRIGGER trg_ai_hits AFTER INSERT ON hits
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE posts SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE id = NEW.postid;
END;
/

DELIMITER ;
```

Although I would not design this way myself, I would not keep track of the number of hits in a table at all! Getting the number of hits is instead something you can do easily at runtime with SQL.

To count the number of hits on a specific post (you want an index on posts.title here):

```
select 
count(1) as hits 
from posts p 
join hits h on p.id = h.postid
where p.title = 'Title 2';
```

To get hits for several posts you can use a GROUP BY clause:

```
select 
p.title, 
count(1) as hits 
from posts p 
join hits h on p.id = h.postid
where p.title in ('Title 2', 'Title 3')
group by p.title
order by hits desc;
```

Also, I think it's good that you store the same IP multiple times. With your current design, you could for example check how many times an IP number has accessed your site:

```
select 
ip, 
count(postid) access_number 
from hits 
group by ip
order by access_number desc;
```

Comment: The challenge is this:
1- When a user open a post page, increase that post hit.
2- If that user open another post, its hit increase.
3- If that user open a post for second time, not to do!

Comment: Then you create an unique index on hits like @gordon-linoff said.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example insert.

Comment: My question is : We want if duplicate occur, do nothing and no error shown ! But if it's a new row, insert it and then update another table column. Just answer this !!

Comment: You use a trigger like gordon already said. See my updated reply for details.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a unique index/constraint on *two* columns rather than one:

```
create unique index unq_hits_postid_ip on hits(postid, ip);
```

Then you can use `on duplicate key update`.

However, this will work on *one* table.  Incrementing a counter in *another* table is a curious design.  Why not just have the counter in `hits`?  If you must increment in another table, then you'll need a trigger.

Comment: No! We want if duplicate occur, do nothing ! But if it's a new row, insert it and then update another table column.